# Nginx - TYPO3 installation - URL behaviour

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-18.04, typo3

First of all, I have to deal with a project-related upgrade of a `TYPO3` version and am also relatively new to the `nginx` web server. Therefore I ask for patience with me.  ;-) I'm also not quite sure, if this question would be better on stackoverflow.com instead of serverfault.com. So if it is a question more for stackoverflow, please let me know, I will transfer it.

As written above, I have upgraded a `TYPO3` installation from version `7.6` to `8.7` and transferred the site from an `IIS` (`windows`) server to an `ubuntu 18.04` system with `nginx`.

I have now discovered the following:
The first click on an internal link on the website in the menu e.g. `domain.com/prices` works correctly. The URL `domain.com/prices` is called and also shown in the URL. Now when the page has been reloaded, the same menu item Link now looks like this...

```
domain.com/index.php?id=8&L=1%20or%20%281%2C2%29%3D%28select%2Afrom%28select%20name_const%28CHAR%28111%2C108%2C111%2C108%2C111%2C115%2C104%2C101%2C114%29%2C1%29%2Cname_const%28CHAR%28111%2C108%2C111%2C108%2C111%2C108%2C111%2C115%2C104%2C101%2C114%29%2C1%29%29a%29%20- -%20and%201%3D1
```

...instead of the usual `domain.com/prices`.
First I thought, it could be an issue with the configuration of `nginx`, but now I think it is a different topic here.
Anybody a hint what can cause this behaviour?
If you need more information, please let me know, I will try to provide it as soon as possible.
Many thanks in advance for your help!

**UPDATE**

I just have seen, that it depends on the extension `real url`. I need to check, how this extension needs to be configured.

Comment: That looks more like an attempt at a SQL injection attack. Are you sure this traffic is legitimate? Are you sure your site is not compromised?

Comment: Actually I cannot say for sure. I will try to find out. But the loaded page from the link(s) are looking correctly, when I click on it. The content is correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. Now I found the solution. It was a config setting of my `typo3` installtion:

```
config.linkVars
```

which was set initially to

```
config.linkVars = L
```

After I found this bug report

https://github.com/dmitryd/typo3-realurl/issues/333

I saw that I need to limit the L-value for security reasons. In our case 0 for german, 1 for english, 2 for french:

```
config.linkVars = L(0-2)
```

Then all worked fine.